# How do you set your LAMP testing server?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, lamp

I am using xampp on Windows, but I would like to use something closer to my server setup.

[Federico Cargnelutti tutorial](http://phpimpact.wordpress.com/2008/05/24/virtual-appliances-lamp-development-made-easy/) explains how to setup LAMP VMWARE appliance; it is a great introduction to VMware appliances, but one of the commands was not working and it doesn't describe how to change the keyboard layout and the timezone.

ps: the commands are easy to find but I don't want to look for them each time I reinstall the server. I am using this question as a reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my install scrpt, I use it on debian servers, but it will work in Ubuntu (Ubuntu is built on Debian)

```
apt-get -yq update
apt-get -yq upgrade
apt-get -yq install sudo
apt-get -yq install gcc
apt-get -yq install g++
apt-get -yq install make
apt-get -yq install apache2
apt-get -yq install php5
apt-get -yq install php5-curl
apt-get -yq install php5-mysql
apt-get -yq install php5-gd
apt-get -yq install mysql-common
apt-get -yq install mysql-client
apt-get -yq install mysql-server
apt-get -yq install phpmyadmin
apt-get -yq install samba
echo '[global]
   workgroup = workgroup
   server string = %h server
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   ;invalid users = root
   unix password sync = no
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   writable = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
[www]
   comment = WWW
   writable = yes
   locking = no
   path = /var/www
   public = yes' > /etc/samba/smb.conf
(echo SAMBAPASSWORD; echo SAMBAPASSWORD) | smbpasswd -sa root
echo 'NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>' > /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
/etc/init.d/samba stop
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
/etc/init.d/samba start
```

edit: add this to set your MySQL password

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
echo "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MySQLPasswrod') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" > /root/MySQLPassword
mysqld_safe --init-file=/root/MySQLPassword &
sleep 1
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
sleep 1
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

end edit

This is a bit specailised but you get the idea, if you save this to a file ('install' for example) all you have to do is:

```
chmod +x install
./install
```

Some of my apt-get commands are not necessary, because apt will automatically get the dependencies but I prefer to be specific, for my installs.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have VMware workstation, VMware player or anything that can run vmware appliance, you just need to:

1. Download, unzip [Ubuntu 8.04 Server](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/1248) and start the virtual machine.
2. Update ubuntu and set the layout and the timezone:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
   sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces
   ```
3. [set a fixed IP](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-ubuntu-linux-convert-dhcp-network-configuration-to-static-ip-configuration.html) (Optional).
4. install apache+mysql+php:

   ```
   sudo tasksel install lamp-server
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Provided this question is properly tagged, you can select LAMP server option during installation of Ubuntu. This will install and configure all required components automatically. A detailed instruction on how to do this can be found, for example, there: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-804-hardy-heron-lamp-server-setup.html

Answer (score 1):

You can rapidly customize LAMP, RoR, Python Django, Java Stack, Spring, etc servers for Ubuntu-based VM images at http://www.elasticserver.com -  Unbuntu 8.04LTS now supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question because i really didn't see one. But i'll do my best to infer two: to change your keyboard layout, check this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=884533&highlight=change+keyboard+layout) on ubuntu forums and to change the timezone, check this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=665255&highlight=change+time+zone).